# log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [..]

Tags: log4j

I am getting following errors on my console repeatedly

```
log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [ConsoleAppender].
log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [FixedWindowRollingFile].
```

### used log4j.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender" name="FixedWindowRollingFile">
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true"/>

        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <param name="fileNamePattern" value="logs/StandardizeAccountService.%i.log"/>
            <param name="minIndex" value="1"/>
            <param name="maxIndex" value="10"/>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1002400"/>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout"/>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.arosys" additivity="false" >
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="FixedWindowRollingFile"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FixedWindowRollingFile"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

please help me where the problem.

Comment: I got the same problem. My solution was upgrading JSTL 1.0 to 1.2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*I've answered similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9973283/340290*

In my case, I've two log4j.properties available to the Log4J: one via placing it in classpath  and other being loaded programmatically (using `PropertyConfigurator.configure(..)`).

And in the two files, I've `ConsoleAppender` registered with same name `stdout` and used for same category twice (one per each properties file). Removing config or the properties file solved my issue.

Comment: I don't see how that solves the original problem asked here, since they don't have multiple files, and they don't have multiple appenders defined with the same name.

Comment: I had the same problem, one log4j in my application and another one inside tomcat/lib. Thanks for this answer!!

Answer (score 29):

I got the same error:

```
log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [rollingFileAppender].
```

In my log4j.xml

I have two loggers with the same name like below

```xml
<logger name="java.sql.PreparedStatement" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="rollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>

 <logger name="java.sql.PreparedStatement">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="rollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```

I removed the duplicate, it worked.

Comment: I got sloppy! missed this!  And Thanks, no less than eight years later!

Answer (score 8):

One could *overwrite* the configuration using:

```java
BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

Comment: Marked this as "my" correct solution because my problem was that I have several potential application entry points, and it's very difficult to refactor it to have a single entry point. I was obtaining the same "Attempted to append to closed appender" error, but the reason was different. Restoring Log4J configuration prior to configuring it again each time has worked for me :-D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify because I was mislead by MaDa answer, additivity=false redirects the output to another place than the default (root logger) and NOT to the default.
See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html chapter "Appenders and Layouts"

Answer (score 1):

This may also mean that you already have your server running, and you're trying to run it again. The second instance can't write to the log file because it's already open in your server.

solution: check to see if your server is already running, and restart it if neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added by mistake 2 "root" elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is the cause of the behaviour you describe (but it *might*), but this part:

```
<logger name="com.arosys" additivity="false" >
   <level value="INFO" />
   <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
   <appender-ref ref="FixedWindowRollingFile"/>
</logger>
```

is pointless. Normally, you'd set a non-additive logger to redirect it *somewhere else* than the default place (your root logger), but you still send the output to the default place. You might as well delete this fragment.