# Classloading in Weblogic 8.1

Tags: java, weblogic, ear, weblogic8.x

I'm dealing with an issue with static singleton that we create for log4j. As per the document [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_%28file_format%29), jboss 4.x and prior used a unified class loader. Meaning, a class deployed in one .ear file can access access class of another ear deployed. So, if one .ear file has already loaded that class, then 2nd .ear does not load it again as it is already loaded.

Does anyone know if this is same for Weblogic 8.1 server? If that is true, I need to change the design of our application.

**Update**: Issue i'm dealing with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066299/log4jerror-attempted-to-append-to-closed-appender-named)

Comment: WebLogic 8.1 is *really* old.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, but our corp is still using it. I have to fix the issues :(

Comment: What issues are those? I don't think there is a unified class loader in Weblogic (but I haven't used 8.1 in a very long time).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i've updated my question with the link to the issue. I  thought I fixed it. But, it popped up within no time.

Comment: WebLogic classloading is definitly hierarchical - finally managed to track down the 8.1 documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/programming/classloading.html#1089798), although is not really changed since then - the latest 12c documentation has the same diagrams!.  That said,  if a class is loaded by the system classloader, then this is sharded by everything, so it might me worth checking the beginning of the server log file it see if log4j is on the server classpath.